# Execute Unix command from Java

Tags: java, shell, unix

In Java how can I execute the following shell command:

```
osmosis --read-xml file="planet-latest.osm" --bounding-polygon file="country.poly" --write-xml file="australia.osm"
```

I tried executing it with this code:

```
Process proc = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("osmosis --read-xml file="planet-latest.osm" --bounding-polygon file="country.poly" --write-xml file="australia.osm"");
InputStream output = proc.getInputStream();
```

but it seems that the Unix command is not executed.

Answer (score 2):

You may need to specify the complete path to osmosis.

Comment: Also, don't forget to escape double quotes. Or better, use overloaded exec method with arrays to pass arguments.

Comment: In addition, I would recommend that he use [Commons-Exec](http://commons.apache.org/exec/tutorial.html) instead of `Runtime.exec()` or `ProcessBuilder`.

Answer (score 1):

Using the Runtime is a deprecated way of executing commands. Take a look at [ProcessBuilder](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html)

Answer (score 1):

try escaping the double "

`Process proc = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("osmosis --read-xml file=\"planet-latest.osm\" --bounding-polygon file=\"country.poly\" --write-xml file=\"australia.osm\"")`

Comment: in Java, a String literal has to start with " (double quotes), your example is starting from a single quote '.